# Android CardView center horizontally

Tags: android, layout, cardview

I have read several answers on how to align a card view horizontally. I am trying to achieve the following:

[Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quLsL.png)

This is so far the code I have written (I have followed around 20 answers from different posts, none which have helped me. The problem is the margin or space on the left and the right, I need that space, but the card view expands the whole width.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/mProjectCDCNumCardView"
                android:layout_marginStart="7dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="7dp"
                android:text="DETAIL"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/mProjectCDCNumCardView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="13dp"
                card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp"
                card_view:contentPaddingLeft="50dp"
                card_view:contentPaddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                card_view:contentPaddingTop="20dp"
                card_view:contentPaddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:background="@drawable/cardview_normal"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView8">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/mProjectCDCNumEditText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:background="@drawable/editborder"
                        android:hint="Project Number"
                        android:inputType="textPersonName"
                        android:padding="10dp" />


            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/mProjectAddressLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:background="@drawable/editborder"
                android:layout_below="@id/mProjectCDCNumCardView"
                android:ems="16"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:hint="Location"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/left_arrow"/>



        </RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

little late to the party here but I really like using **ConstraintLayouts**. It is super easy to center Views in them.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

     ... Content ...

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This code will center **CardView** inside of the ConstraintLayout that has the same width as parent. The CardView has width of 200dp and thanks to the constraints it will be centered horizontaly in the Layout.

[More info about ConstraintLayout.](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/)

Answer (score 1):

1. In your CardView component, add a **LinearLayout** component.
2. Add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` property to your LinearLayout.
3. In your LinearLayout component add your EditText component.

   ```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
       app:cardElevation="4dp"
       app:cardCornerRadius="3dp">
       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:gravity="center_horizontal">
           <EditText
                   android:id="@+id/mProjectCDCNumEditText"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                   android:background="@drawable/editborder"
                   android:hint="Project Number"
                   android:inputType="textPersonName"
                   android:padding="10dp" />
       </LinearLayout>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You just add android:layout_marginStart and android:layout_marginEnd to your cardview.

Answer (score 0):

The height attribute of your layout must be match_parent.